# Using marqee.js plug in & attempting to switch between two(three??) states of css reflection for an async call (ie.ajax)

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, asynchronous, marquee

Using the marqee.js plug in, I am attempting to switch between two states of css reflection while updating one array to newArray & set newArray to as former state of array; basically a = b, b = c, c = a. This will be updated through an async ajax call and be reflected in the 'hide/show' state of the 'b' array.

I have tried to add additional features and it only ends up scrolling css only for one of the two marquee's i'm trying either marquee or marquee1.
https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee
visited the developer's codepen.io and many, many days of trying...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Random marquee text</h1>
<div class='marquee'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END.
</div>
<div class='marquee1'>
This is the one of a long array END.
</div>
</body>
```

```
<style>
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.marquee1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background: black;
    color: rgb(202, 255, 195);
}
</style>
<scripts>
$(window).ready(function(){ //*window for images();
    $('.marquee').marquee({   //, .marquee1 removed   
        duration: 6000,//speed in milliseconds of the marquee    
        gap: 50,//gap in pixels between the tickers    
        delayBeforeStart: 0,//marquee delay before init start 
        direction: 'right',//'left' or 'right'`enter code here`
        duplicated: true//true or false 
    });
$('.marquee')
      .bind('finished', function() {
         // $(this).marquee('beforeStart') not working
        $(this).marquee('destroy');//marquee loads new ajax data
        $(this).html('Some new data loaded using ajax')
          .marquee()//Apply marquee plugin again
    })
 });  
</scripts>
```

Ideally, from an array trigger a marquee update w said change.
2: beforeStart load "Welcome"
3: icon pics prepending (test: atRandom) for any icons or lorempixel
4: and each ajax string
Goal: to update a scroll ticker - i've already made it, it scrolls!
Have an array taken in and displayed; Yes! it does that.
have an array toggle(?) between states then return as set to the original state with the information of the updated state.
In essence, a = b, b = c, c = a. This will be updated through an async ajax call and be reflected in the 'hide/show' state of the 'b' array. & it’s not doing that. Pls help. Thx stkOflComm